# Eclipse plug'in: how to provide input for the editor

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to develop a plugin that will render the elements of an XML file in a tree view and (on double-click) is supposed to open the file in an editor. The file in question is a plugin resource.

Most of the examples I've seen get the file as an IFile from selection (the selected element); my problem is I can't find a way to provide that input otherwise.
Here is a couple of example of what I've already tried:

```
IProject project= ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject("the plugin project");
IFile file = testProject.getFile("test.xml");
```

and

```
IWorkspace workspace= ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
IPath location= new Path(relative path); // local to the project directory
IFile file= workspace.getRoot().getFileForLocation(location);
```

Somehow the file I'm looking for is not found.
I've managed to render the tree by reading the file from a stream provided by:

```
MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(relativePath);
```

I could get the Url to the file (using getResource()) but I don't know if I can use it to get the IFile I need.
Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say `location` is relative to the project directory, however you are trying to resolve it using [workspace.getRoot().getFileForLocation()](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IWorkspaceRoot.html#getFileForLocation%28org.eclipse.core.runtime.IPath%29), whose JavaDoc says,

> The path should be absolute; a relative path will be treated as absolute.

Comment: Thank you for answering.
I have to say this is really peculiar (bear with please me I'm just a beginner in his quest for knowledge), I tried the absolute path just to get it to work but "file" is null and raises an exception.. I was thinking maybe it was looking for the file in the workspace open in the eclipse (which is a temporary one used for testing) that would explain why I couldn't find the project in the first example. Could this be right?

Comment: So, does your path look like `/myProject/path/inside/project/myfile.txt`, where `myProject` is a workspace project in the Eclipse instance your are running the code in?

Comment: Well I've tried various paths (out of desperation) using the eclipse debugger. I tried that one along with:
 filename/
& /filename
& /folder/filename & folder/filename
& /project/folder/filename

Comment: OK, http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.ide.eclipse.platform.core.devel/608 says that the absolute path means a file in your file system, not the workspace. Please have a look at [this Eclipse doc](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2FresInt_filesystem.htm) about resource handling. In short, your first version should work, but for that you need an up-to-date resource tree of your project (i.e. you should be able to see `test.xml` in the `Project Explorer`).

Comment: Whew! Good luck in the Eclipse programming! :)